# famo.us quaternion rotation around z axis

Tags: rotation, quaternions, famo.us

As far as I know a quaternion is a set of four values (W X Y Z) that are used to specify a rotation in 3D space. For a given axis (x y z) and angle (α), the quaternion representing a rotation around the axis from the origin (0,0,0) to (x,y,z). So a rotation of 90 degrees about the z axis (0 0 1) should be:

```
var quaternion = new Quaternion(Math.PI/2, 0, 0, 1);
```

but famo.us turns it for ~60 degrees...

I've also tried `var quaternion = new Quaternion(90, 0, 0, 1);` but in this case famo.us turns it for ~5 degrees

is it a bug of the framework?
How should I use it to turn it on 90 degreez around z axis?
 Documentation is still totally useless..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this method `Quaternion.makeFromAngleAndAxis(angle, v)`
I have found this to be the most straight forward approach to making it a little more readable and useable.

**[Example jsBin](http://jsbin.com/sijiza/1/edit?js,output)**

#### Where

```js
var degrees = 90;    
var angle = Math.PI/180 * degrees;
var v = new Vector(0, 0, 1);

var quaternion = new Quaternion();
quaternion.makeFromAngleAndAxis(angle, v);
```

...To get the transform

```
quaternion.getTransform();
```

#### Something to remember from Math Class

A circle has 360 degrees.  Each degree is represented by the unit circumference of a circle 2 * PI * r. We will assume we have a radius of 1. So divide your total circumference by 360 and you get one degrees 2PI/360 or PI/180.

In Summary:

- one degrees of our circle is = Math.PI/180
- your angle of direction is = Math.PI/180 * degrees

Answer (score 0):

Just found answer in one wiki article:

```
var angle = Math.PI/2;
var axis = [0,0,1];

var w = Math.cos(.5 * angle);
var x = axis[0] * Math.sin(.5 * angle);
var y = axis[1] * Math.sin(.5 * angle);
var z = axis[2] * Math.sin(.5 * angle);
var quaternion = new Quaternion(w, x, y, z);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this transformation - Transform.rotateZ(angle);

Refer to - http://famo.us/docs/reference/pages/0.3/transforms.html